# The limit of a sequence with a sum notation

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:}\left(\sum _{k=1}^n\:\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4}+k}\right)$$

The limit is not my problem, evaluation the sum is.

here is what i've got so far:

$$ \lim _{n\to \infty }\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\:n\:\cdot\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\:\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4}+k}\right)\right) $$

then

$$\lim _{n\to \infty \:} n^2\:\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4+n\left(n+1\right)}}\right) $$

is this even true? i get 0 times infinity, but i can get over it, if its true :/

Comment: is it $$\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{n}{\sqrt{n^4+k}}$$?

Comment: Do you mean $\lim _{n\to \infty \:}$? Also, how did you get a double sigma? You should be getting $n$, not $n^2$.

Comment: Somebody is trying to be funny: $\sqrt{n^4}=n^2$.

Comment: @ElieLouis yes i meant the limit (edited it), about $$ n^2\: $$ isn't the sum of a number is that number times n ?

Comment: Hint: $\displaystyle\frac{n}{n^2+n}\le\frac{n}{n^2+k}<\frac{n}{n^2}$

Comment: Well you here you have $\sum n c_{k} $, which is $n \sum c_{k}.$ I mean, $n$ is a constant with respect to the sum, so you can get it out of the summation. If you multiply every term by a constant $n$, you will get n times the sum, not $n^2$ times the sum.

Comment: so its going to be $$ n\:\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n^4+n\left(n+1\right)}}\right) $$ , @ProfessorVector  i don't know how to use that hint..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $$\frac{n}{n^2+n}\le\frac{n}{n^2+k}<\frac{n}{n^2}$$ for $1\le k\le n$,
$$\frac{n}{n+1}=n\cdot\frac{n}{n^2+n}\le\sum^n_{k=1}\frac{n}{n^2+k}<n\cdot\frac{n}{n^2}=1,$$ so your limit is $1$.

Comment: thx, may i ask what's the name of this? i mean i never studied sum notation, i saw it first in the limit and just googled it and took the general method to solve, so what should i study to be more good at it (since i have more limits like this to solve.) thanks.